# Lost all desktop settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, virus

I'm using windows 7. I logged in one morning and found my desktop background was black, and I had lost all my desktop icons & settings. I then found that I could not open any application - it would give me the pop-up error "These files can't be opened. Your Internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened." I can't even open IE to change the security settings. I can't open regedit either. What could have caused this? Virus? Corrupt profile?

Comment: Sounds like your computer is infected with a virus. See http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc

Comment: Do you have any AV program? Can you run it? Does the start menu open? Can you run applications from start menu? Can you open the PC in safe mode?

Comment: I have AVG, but can't run it. I can open the start menu but cannot run anything. I can't find a safe mode when I enter boot options. What I have managed to do, however, is create a new admin user and log in as that user, and can do everything from there. I have run AVG and Malwarebytes, but they don't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting Windows in safe mode and see if problem persists there. To boot into safe mode, restart the computer and start tapping [F8] as soon as you see the boot logo. If problem still persists even in safe mode, it's time to backup all your files, format the hard drive and reinstall Windows from scratch.

If you can't backup your files because Windows Explorer does not launch, you can create a [bootable Ubuntu USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). You won't need to install Ubuntu, you can start it directly from USB and backup all your files to external hard disc from within Ubuntu's interface. Next, you can safely format your system HDD and install a fresh copy of Windows.

Comment: When I go into boot options from F8, I don't get a safe mode option. I have an Acronis backup from last week I can revert to, which I've pretty much decided to do at this point. Thanks anyway.